# My if statement is not printing text in python

Tags: python-2.7

Lately I've been having issues with python especially with if statements. Below I have a simple if statement that prints the string 'did it work?' when the variable greeting is equal to hello.

```
greeting = raw_input('hi')
if greeting == 'hello':
    print 'did it work?'
```

I run this python file in the terminal only to enter the word hello into the variable greeting and to get nothing back. I don't get why the if statement doesn't work. Below is a link to what my terminal output looks like.

[Terminal Outout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiJaN.png)

This has really to get on my nerves, it's stopping me from working on my program and it's made me want to throw my laptop across the room. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you running it in a windows environment ?

Comment: If you mean the operating system then no, I run linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are entering a space before the "hello" word. Test with:

```
greeting = raw_input('hi')
if greeting.strip() == 'hello':
    print 'did it work?'
```

Comment: Sure looks like that's the case... of course, if the OP did: `raw_input('hi ')` with a space in it, they wouldn't be wanting to hit the spacebar before entering the greeting...

Comment: Thank You! Your code worked! I am now going to try to fix the actual program I've been working on.

Comment: @nax You are comparing string in the `if` sentence. So both strings have to be exactly equal to be True the result of the `==` operand. That is a pretty standard thing in most programming languages. The `greeting ` variable has to be equal character by character to the literal `hello`, that means no space, no different upper or lower case for each character, and so on.

Comment: I just noticed the space, so I edited my reply. I do know about the == operand and how it works though. I can't believe it was that space the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

It is working fine for me. Check https://repl.it/K2ro/1

You might be giving extra space before most probably or after. Try trimming the string before operating on it, for your particular case you should use "strip()".

Answer (score 0):

Check your `greeting` variable after you input `"hello"`
Do a `print` of `greeting` and it's `len()` and check if there is anything unusual